# Yolo-v3 object detection with python

Tags: python-3.x, yolo, darknet

I'm trying to detect objects using Yolo-v3 referring [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introduction-to-implementing-the-yolo-algorithm-for-multi-object-detection-in-images-99cf240539) tutorial. I have already installed darknet.

When I tried to run the following code:

```
from darknet import Darknet
```

it says:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Darknet' from 'darknet' (unknown location)

so I tried:

```
import darknet as dn
net = dn.load_net("cfg/tiny-yolo.cfg", "tiny-yolo.weights", 0)
```

then it says:

> "AttributeError: module 'darknet' has no attribute 'load_net'"

How I can avoid these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from utils import *
from darknet import Darknet
net = Darknet("cfg/tiny-yolo.cfg")
net.load_weights("tiny-yolo.weights")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Instead of using the original darknet.py, I used this one https://github.com/Garima13a/YOLO-Object-Detection/blob/master/darknet.py.

Comment: I can't find this `dn.load_net` in this link. Try my answer now.